# In Excel, how do I select specific rows in a table based on matching criteria in a separate table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet of account records (table 1) and I need to select only those rows that meet/match multiple criteria conditions in a separate Excel sheet (table 2)

For example, I need to select only the rows in table 1 where the "BalanceBand" is a match between the two tables, the "ScoreBand" is a match between the two tables, AND the "Selected Units" in the second table is greater than 0. So, I am taking a single row at a time in the account table and need to run it through the entire second table to see if there is a match.

TABLE 1

| Account | BuyID | Status | Balance | BalanceBand | ExperianScore | ExperianScoreBand | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4564077 | PEN033 | DECEASED | 12532.74 | $10,000-20,000 | 0 | UNSCORED | MN |
| 4564078 | PEN033 | PTPPLC | 20618.8 | $20,000+ | 713 | 700-750 | GA |
| 4564079 | PEN033 | PTPPLC | 1601.21 | $1,000-2,000 | 623 | 600-650 | PR |
| 4564080 | PEN033 | JORMANDY | 26378.45 | $20,000+ | 619 | 600-650 | CO |
| 4564081 | PEN033 | PTPPLC | 17330.38 | $10,000-20,000 | 647 | 600-650 | TX |
| 4564082 | PEN033 | NEWACCTPLC | 1594.42 | $1,000-2,000 |  | UNSCORED | TX |
| 4564083 | PEN033 | PTPPLC | 20097.07 | $20,000+ | 622 | 600-650 | MD |

TABLE 2

| Balance Band | ScoreBand | Units | Balance | Weight % |  | GL % | GL $ | CC | CC Recoupment | Contingency Fee | NL | ROI |  | Units | Selected Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1,000-2,000 | 400-450 | 1 | 1,606 | 0.03% |  | 15% | 239 | 165 | 79 | 64 | 88 | 0.53x |  | 1 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 450-500 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 56% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 500-550 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 24% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 550-600 | 2 | 3,756 | 0.07% |  | 24% | 894 | 330 | 158 | 241 | 480 | 1.46x |  | 2 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 600-650 | 4 | 6,457 | 0.12% |  | 30% | 1,955 | 660 | 316 | 528 | 1,083 | 1.64x |  | 4 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 650-700 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 28% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 700-750 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 40% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 750-800 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 32% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | 800-850 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 0% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $1,000-2,000 | Unscored | 43 | 68,235 | 1.23% |  | 6% | 4,096 | 7,095 | 3,397 | 1,106 | (708) | -0.10x |  | 43 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 400-450 | 3 | 8,374 | 0.15% |  | 12% | 1,032 | 495 | 237 | 279 | 495 | 1.00x |  | 3 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 450-500 | 8 | 19,512 | 0.35% |  | 11% | 2,092 | 1,320 | 632 | 565 | 839 | 0.64x |  | 8 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 500-550 | 10 | 26,743 | 0.48% |  | 13% | 3,574 | 1,650 | 790 | 965 | 1,749 | 1.06x |  | 10 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 550-600 | 10 | 25,808 | 0.47% |  | 13% | 3,259 | 1,650 | 790 | 880 | 1,519 | 0.92x |  | 10 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 600-650 | 2 | 4,674 | 0.08% |  | 10% | 462 | 330 | 158 | 125 | 166 | 0.50x |  | 2 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 650-700 | 1 | 2,609 | 0.05% |  | 12% | 322 | 165 | 79 | 87 | 149 | 0.90x |  | 1 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 700-750 | 1 | 2,389 | 0.04% |  | 13% | 311 | 165 | 79 | 84 | 141 | 0.85x |  | 1 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | 750-800 | 1 | 2,904 | 0.05% |  | 47% | 1,379 | 165 | 79 | 372 | 920 | 5.58x |  | 1 | 1 |
| $2,000-3,000 | 800-850 | 0 | - | 0.00% |  | 0% | - | - | - | - | - | 0.00x |  | 0 | - |
| $2,000-3,000 | Unscored | 11 | 26,643 | 0.48% |  | 8% | 2,161 | 1,815 | 869 | 584 | 632 | 0.35x |  | 11 | - |
| $3,000-5,000 | 400-450 | 5 | 19,239 | 0.35% |  | 57% | 10,959 | 825 | 395 | 2,959 | 7,570 | 9.18x |  | 5 | 5 |
| $3,000-5,000 | 450-500 | 20 | 75,466 | 1.36% |  | 20% | 15,238 | 3,300 | 1,580 | 4,114 | 9,404 | 2.85x |  | 20 | 20 |

I tried many combinations of INDEX, MATCH, COUNTIF, and VLOOKUP but could never get it to work like I wanted. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want us to type over the data from the screenshot to try? That's unlikely to happen. Please use markdown tables to share data as table. You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Selected units (Table 2) are almost all `-` leaving 3 options for Selected units > 0 and none match required conditions in Table 1. What would be your expected result and (even more important) why?

Comment: Both tables are actually much larger so only a snapshot of each was provided as a reference. I need to select individual account records from Table 1 where the BalanceBand and ScoreBand combination match in Table 2 and where SelectedUnits > 0

Comment: So give a sample of records including matches and it's expected result and share at least your attempt of COUNTIF(S) and/or MATCH

Answer (score 0):

This was quite challenging, since the first and second table don't have the matching ID's, but this should do the trick:

```
=FILTER(Table1,
        MMULT(
              (TRANSPOSE(Table4[Balance Band])=Table1[BalanceBand])*(TRANSPOSE(Table4[ScoreBand])=Table1[ExperianScoreBand]),
              --(ISNUMBER(Table4[Selected Units]))),
        "no matches")
```

Alternatively:

```
=FILTER(Table1, 
        BYROW(Table1,LAMBDA(b,LET(bb,INDEX(b,,5),sb,INDEX(b,,7),
        SUMPRODUCT((Table4[Balance Band]=bb)*(Table4[ScoreBand]=sb)*(ISNUMBER(Table4[Selected Units])))))))
```